# RecyclerView with swipe not propagating swipe to a ViewPager row

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, swipe

I´m trying to have a RecyclerView with different ViewHolders. Some of them may be able to be swiped and others don´t. 
Te problem is that I have a ViewHolder with a ViewPager inside (acting like a carousel of pictures) and I don´y want to be swiped (RecyclerView swipe), I want to preserve it´s own swipe for swiping between pages (pictures).

¿How can I propagate the swipe gesture from the RecyclerView to the ViewHolder just in those cases?

I´ve been trying to recognize if the swiped ViewHolder is the one how has the ViewPager and propagate the swipe gesture but I can´t find the way to do it.

This is my RecyclerView layout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

This is my ItemTouchHelperCallback

```
public class SwipeHelperCallback extends ItemTouchHelper.Callback {

    public interface ItemTouchHelperListener {
        void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction);
    }

    Context context;
    ItemTouchHelperListener mListener;

    public SwipeHelperCallback(Context context, ItemTouchHelperListener mListener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mListener = mListener;
    }

    @Override
    public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        int swipeFlags = ItemTouchHelper.START | ItemTouchHelper.END;

        return makeMovementFlags(0, swipeFlags);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

        if (viewHolder instanceof CardMiniViewHolder ||
                viewHolder instanceof CardBlogViewHolder) {
            mListener.onSwiped(viewHolder, direction);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isItemViewSwipeEnabled() {
        return true;
    }



    @Override
    public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {


        if (actionState== ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE) {
            View v = viewHolder.itemView;                
            if (viewHolder instanceof CardMiniViewHolder ||
                    viewHolder instanceof CardBlogViewHolder) {
                v.findViewById(R.id.foreground).setTranslationX(dX);
            }
        } else {
            super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void clearView(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        super.clearView(recyclerView, viewHolder);
        if (viewHolder instanceof CardMiniViewHolder ||
                viewHolder instanceof CardBlogViewHolder) {
            viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.foreground).setTranslationX(0);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my ViewHolder and layout of my carousel row (the ViewPager)

(Layout)

```
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="text"
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorTextDark"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/layout"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

(ViewHolder)

```
public class CardAlbumViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements AlbumPagerAdapter.OnViewPagerClickListener {

    ViewPager viewPager;
    TextView imageIndicatorText;
    Album album;
    Context context;
    int total;

    public CardAlbumViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        context = itemView.getContext();
        viewPager = (ViewPager) itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        imageIndicatorText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);

    }

    public void bind(Album album) {
        this.album = album;
        total = album.getImageUrlsArrayList().size()+1;
        viewPager.setAdapter(new AlbumPagerAdapter(viewPager.getContext(), album, this));
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                imageIndicatorText.setText(String.format("%d/%d", position + 1, total));
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
        imageIndicatorText.setText(String.format("%d/%d", 1, total));
    }


    @Override
    public void onPageClick(int position) {
        Log.i("click", "album");
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlbumActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("album", album);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```